# remembering variables in select box

Tags: php, variables

I have This Code In HTML

```
<tr>
<td>
Gender:
</td>
<td>
<select name="Gender">
<option selected="" value="Default">
Gender
</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have completed the validation in php. but the problem is when i hit the submitbutton and php code gives error the option goes back to Default. i have read similar questions to this.
But is there a php code like if gender is selected as male echo male else echo Default. Because i have selected option for default.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Amod(India)

Comment: show us you php code. It will be very helpful

Comment: can you explain more what you want to do?

Comment: My php code just validates weather IF Default option is selected i errors choose your gender

Comment: what i need is that when i hit submit button the selected option should be displayed as default

Comment: you can use javascript validation too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is this:

```
<select name="Gender">
  <option>
    Gender
  </option>
  <option <?php if ($_POST['Gender'] == "Male") echo "selected"; ?> value="Male">
    Male
  </option>
  <option <?php if ($_POST['Gender'] == "Female") echo "selected"; ?> value="Female">
    Female
  </option>
</select>
```

Of course, it's much easier if you use autogenerated options with a loop (keeping your code DRY).

EDIT: if nothing was selected, the first option will be selected by default. Give this no value. There's some more valuable information in [this User Experience question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/13413)

```
<select name="Gender">
  <option>
    Gender
  </option>
  <?php foreach (array('Male', 'Female') as $Gender) { ?>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['Gender'] == $Gender) echo "selected"; ?> value="<?php echo $Gender; ?>">
      <?php echo $Gender; ?>
    </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And if you have short tags enabled, you could do:

```
<select name="Gender">
  <option>
    Gender
  </option>
  <? foreach (array('Male', 'Female') as $Gender) { ?>
    <option <? if ($_POST['Gender'] == $Gender) echo "selected"; ?> value="<?= $Gender; ?>">
      <?= $Gender; ?>
    </option>
  <? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thnk you very much. I did even not blnk my eye i got a good answer

Comment: Frank you should check `isset($_POST['Gender'])` else it will give notice  and warning

Comment: Just added a couple more edits (;

Comment: dont use short tag `<? ?>` most of the server not support it

Comment: @YadavChetan It depends on the case, I don't think it's needed in this case to check if it's set (not critical).

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos but as a good programmer we should have habbit of check it :)

Comment: I am sorry but I disagree with that while I agree with first part of "Your Common Sense" (an user) in [an answer he gave me a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429030/938236). He said: `these notices aren't only to make your busy fighting them. They are for help, not to make your code complicated. You just need to be sure what variables you operate. And adding bulk if(empty()) won't do any good.` As you can see there, I would agree with you back then, just not now. But I agree about short tags.